# The Probability of Rolling a Large Straight with 5 Six-Sided Dice

Tags: probability, dice

I don't know the probability of rolling a large straight with 5 six-sided dice, so I need to know what the probability is.  What is it?

Comment: Matthew Conroy, it's about getting different consecutive numbers on every die in different ways

Comment: But now I know!  It's a 48 in 7,776 chance of rolling a large straight.

Comment: I hope this answer is right, you know, the probability comment that's above this one that I answered yesterday (Tuesday, November 26, 2013).  Also, why should comments typed in by yourself be edited up to 5 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

The probability of rolling 1-2-3-4-5 in that order is $(1/6)^5$.  However any order will do, so it's $5!(1/6)^5$.

The probability of rolling 2-3-4-5-6 is similarly $5!(1/6)^5$.

Combining, we get $240(1/6)^5\approx 0.03$, i.e. about 3% of the time.

Comment: Wow!  That's amazing!  Awesome!  Fantastic!  I can't believe you used a factorial and an exponent to figure that out!  You also used a similarity thing!  Another thing you used is an "approximately equal to" sign to approximate the answer.  No doubt about it!

Comment: You're welcome, glad to be of service.

Comment: But I didn't even say "Thank you." and how are you out of service?  Also, how can you be glad when you're out of service?!